# MVC create record

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

View Code:

```
@model EI.Models.QuoteModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    //a bunch of input fields

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Controller code:

```
    public ActionResult Create(QuoteModel qm) {
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            db.QuoteModels.Add(qm);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I fill out the fields on the view and click "Create" and it doesn't make it to the Create method.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't explicitly specified an actionName in your `BeginForm` helper, this assumes that the view was rendered from a controller action with the same name and in the same controller:

```
public ActionResult Create(int id) {
    var qm = db.QuoteModels.Single(id);
    return View(qm);
}
```

If it isn't then you should explicitly specify the action name:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", null, FormMethod.Post))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the action name in the `BeginForm` method like so

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "ControllerName")) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    //a bunch of input fields

    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

It is necessary to provide the names if the name of the view file does not match the action name.